# Removing all elements of a column in a two-dimensional array

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array:

```
arr = [["a","b","c"],[2,3,5],[3,6,8],[1,3,1]]
```

which is representing a prawn-table containing columns "a", "b", and "c".

How do I remove the entire column "c" with all its values, 5, 8, 1?

Maybe there are useful hints in "[Create two-dimensional arrays and access sub-arrays in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720932/create-two-dimensional-arrays-and-access-sub-arrays-in-ruby)" and "[difficulty modifying two dimensional ruby array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012666/difficulty-modifying-two-dimensional-ruby-array)" but I can't transfer them to my problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just out of curiosity sake here is an another approach (one-liner):

```
arr.transpose[0..-2].transpose
```

Comment: or just `arr.transpose[2]` to return the column.

Comment: @MarkReed I'd rather suggest ```arr.transpose.last``` or ```arr.transpose[-1]``` as a more generic solution.

Comment: @MarkReed we have `Array#pop`, it will do the job greatly as I posted. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
 arr = [["a","b","c"],[2,3,5],[3,6,8],[1,3,1]]

 i = 2   # the index of the column you want to delete
 arr.each do |row|
   row.delete_at i
 end

  => [["a", "b"], [2, 3], [3, 6], [1, 3]] 

 class Matrix < Array
   def delete_column(i)
     arr.each do |row|
      row.delete_at i
     end
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 3):

Since it is just the last value you can use `Array#pop`:

```
arr.each do |a|
  a.pop
end
```

Or find the index of `"c"` and delete all elements at that index:

```
c_index = arr[0].index "c"
arr.each do |a|
  a.delete_at c_index
end
```

Or using `map`:

```
c_index = arr[0].index "c"
arr.map{|a| a.delete_at c_index }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arr.map { |row| row.delete_at(2) } 
#=> ["c", 5, 8, 1]
```

That's if you really want to remove the last column so it's not in the original array anymore.  If you just want to return it while leaving `arr` intact:

```
arr.map { |row| row[2] }
#=> ["c", 5, 8, 1]
```

If you want to delete all the elements in a column corresponding to a particular heading:

```
if index = arr.index('c') then
   arr.map { |row| row[index] }  # or arr.map { |row| row.delete_at(index) }
end
```

Comment: needs to be `if index = arr[0].index('c')`

Answer (score 1):

```
# Assuming first row are headers
arr = [["a","b","c"],[2,3,5],[3,6,8],[1,3,1]]

col = arr.first.index "c"
arr.each { |a| a.delete_at(col) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the array's first element is always an array of column names, then you could do:

```
def delete_column(col, array)
  index = array.first.index(col)
  return unless index
  array.each{ |a| a.delete_at(index) }
end
```

It will modify the passed-in array. You shouldn't assign its output to anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [["a","b","c"],[2,3,5],[3,6,8],[1,3,1]]
arr.map(&:pop)
p arr #=> [["a", "b"], [2, 3], [3, 6], [1, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a more generic need to remove one or more column**s** that matched a text pattern (not just delete the last column).

```
 col_to_delete = 'b'
 arr = [["a","b","c"],[2,3,5],[3,6,8],[1,3,1]]
 arr.transpose.collect{|a| a if (a[0] != col_to_delete)}.reject(&:nil?).transpose
 => [["a", "c"], [2, 5], [3, 8], [1, 1]]
```